# Set email notification on build failure - Team City

Tags: teamcity

I have configured Team City to send email via EC2 and that works fine, but how do I now set an email account to send failure notifications for all build jobs on the server? I bet the answer is staring me in the face, but I just can't see it.  TC 7.x BTW.

============== EDIT ==============

I know how to do this on an individual basis, but I want to set an email notification globally to an address which is a group address.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got the behavior I wanted by creating a new user account, setting the email address to the group alias address and setting the notification for the account as required.